# make a proxy with two servers

Tags: linux, ssh, proxy, linux-networking

I want to implement a proxy which has two (A and B) servers in the middle. traffic goes from my computer to server B and then to server A and then gets the data.
I found that with this configuration in ~/.ssh/config:

```
HOST B
    HostName B
    user debian
    DynamicForward 0.0.0.0:1081
```

I can use my 1081 port as a proxy. But now I don't know how to proxy all B's traffic through A.

Comment: create a vpn its easier

Comment: @djdomi What do you mean by creating vpn? because of some controlling policies which my ISP has I can't use tools like shadowsocks

Comment: openvpn i. e. if you need to do like

Answer (score 0):

You want a port on your client to be forwarded to a fixed port on server `A`:

```
ssh -L 1080:localhost:1081 A
```

Here `localhost` is server `A`. On port 1081 on server `A` you must have a dynamic (SOCKS5) proxy:

```
ssh -D 1081 B
```

Putting it all together:

```
ssh -t -L 1080:localhost:1081 A -- ssh -D 1081 B
```

if you use password based authentication between host A and B, or

```
ssh -f -L 1080:localhost:1081 A -- ssh -D 1081 B
```

if you use public key authentication and want your `ssh` to go work in the background.

Comment: I get this error: Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
Host key verification failed.

Comment: If you use password based authentication between host A and B, you need to force the allocation of a (pseudo-)terminal on server A, so you can enter your password. I edited the answer accordingly.